# Landing on php file from an unintended source

Tags: php, html

I suspect this question is asked before but I am having trouble wording it in one sentence so apologies if it is a duplicate but I did ask Google quite a lot but getting answers totally irrelevant to what I am trying to find out.

A bit of context
I have a bunch of html and php files that deal with authentication.
I have a login.html form that calls home.php which (1) authenticates user based on username and password and then (2) displays home screen. So the home.php has the following variable assignments:

```
$username = $_POST[“username”];

$password = $_POST[“password”];
```

The problem is when I am using a different file “change_password.php” which is called from a form in “change_password.html.” In the php file, there are only three variables: $oldpword, $newpword and $newconfirmationpword which is all I need to change password. And once the password is successfully changed, I expect the user to press the “home” button (home.php).

However, when the home button is selected and the home.php file is run, I get an error saying that the variable $username and $password is undefined. I suspect it is because the form that called the change_password.php file did not have $username and $password variables in their `<input>` element. As such, when the two assignment codes are run, the $_POST[] variables are empty (or undefined).

Is there a way around this? My ultimate aim is to get rid of the undefined errors.

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST array is available everywhere since it is a super global.
You can access these values anywhere you'd like. Just make sure that you have used session_start();

```
$username = $_POST[“username”];

$password = $_POST[“password”];
```

Set the variables BEFORE you use them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to define first the variable. You can do try

$username = $_POST[“username”] ? $_POST[“username”] : '';

$password = $_POST[“password”]? $_POST[“password”] : '';